# Does using the Double Equals in JavaScript Cause Performance Issues?

Tags: javascript, performance, if-statement, boolean

Per "strict mode" in JavaScript, you should use `===` when comparing values in an if-statement. However, when dealing with truthy/falsy values, this can lead to very long if-statements:

`if (a !== null && a !== undefined && a !== '' && a !== 0) {}`

To get around this, I've started using `!!`

`if(!!a === true) {}`

to cast the value as a boolean. However, I'm concerned there's a performance impact. According to my JSPerf (http://jsperf.com/double-exclamation-vs-falsy/4), This approach is 30% slower than the long form of the if-statement.

Am I way off base here? Has anyone else noticed a performance hit?

Comment: There's rarely a need for an explicit comparison to `true` or `false`.  Just `if (a)` will do the trick.

Comment: if using `!!` then there is no need for `=== true` or `=== false`

Comment: @PatrickEvans and if you leave off the comparison, there's no need for `!!` either.

Comment: In theory `==` is less performant, because it requires type coercion. But `!!a` basically does what JS would do have you used `==` (i.e. converting the operand to boolean).

Comment: I understand that you can use ``if(a)`` but I mention in my question that I'm sticking to strict mode standards and using triple equals. My question is specifically about the performance impact of ``!!``

Comment: I don't think that is a strict standard is it?  Even in Mozilla's example of strict they are using if(condition) since truthy and falsy evaluate the same way.   I would imagine the performance hit may come from writing several unecessary characters making the source code larger. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

Comment: `if (a)` is absolutely, totally OK in strict mode. In fact the exact same behavior that makes `if (!!a === true)` work is what makes plain old `if (a)` work - the implicit truthiness test in the application of `!` is *exactly* the same as the truthiness test in `if (a)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `if(!!a) {` does have a significant performance hit because you're doing the same boolean conversion that JS does internally when you do `if(a)`. It is more performant to do explicit type checking like `if(a === true)` or `if(a !== null && a !== undefined)`

Comment: `if (a != null)` is *exactly* the same as `if (a !== null && a !== undefined)`, for what it's worth.